# PyDev tagging wsadmin (WebSphere) commands as "Undefined variable" in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, websphere, pydev, jython, wsadmin

I am, running Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) with PyDev for Eclipse (2.8.2).

My Jython interpreter is pointing to "`C:\jython2.1.0\jython.jar`" and "`C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServerV85\optionalLibraries\jython\jython.jar`".

My Python interpreter is pointing to "`C:\Python-2.1.3\python.exe`".

I created a new PyDev project with a file called "testJython.py". It runs against my local WebSphere environment by connecting to the server process with a SOAP connector. The script executes successfully.

The part I am having trouble with is the intepretation of the Jython code that is WebSphere specific. For example, in the line of code "`AdminControl.queryNames("*:*,type=ConfigRepository,process=nodeagent")`" Eclipse throws out an error on "`AdminControl`". It underlines it in red and shows "Undefined variable: AdminControl".

It seems to me that I am missing a configuration in Eclipse (or in the code) to load the WebSphere internal commands properly (i.e. import a class or something).

Can someone help me configure PyDev correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. Here is an IBM website on how to use wsadmin with PyDev:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1209_vansickel/1209_vansickel.html